# How to get success count and error count in batch apex

Tags: apex, batch, singleemailmessage, asyncapexjob

```
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
 AsyncApexJob a [Select Id, Status, ExtendedStatus, NumberOfErrors, JobItems Processed, TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Emailfrom AsyncApexJob where Id =:bc.getJobId()];

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

String[] toAddresses new String[] {a. CreatedBy. Email}; 
mail.setToAddresses (toAddresses);
mail.setSubject('Match Merge Batch + a.Status);
mail.setPlainTextBody('Success Count + a. TotalJobItems+ '\nError Count + a.NumberOfErrors ); Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail });
```

Comment: Your batch needs to track the number of successfully processed records, and the number of failures, in the `execute` method using some instance attributes/properties on the class. This means you'll need to make sure your batch implements `Database.Stateful` too.

Answer (score 1):

Batch Apex is stateless by default. That means for each execution of your execute method, you receive a fresh copy of your object. All fields of the class are initialized, static and instance.
Make use of Database.Stateful,to maintain variable value inside the Batch class. Then use this variable to store the records which are processed successfully/failed which can be used in finish method.
[Find documentation here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm)

Comment: Please mark this as answer if it helped